# Getting Data From a Huge JSON File and Transfer it to CSV or SQL

Tags: php, sql, json

Originally I have JSON file containing 1Million+ books Information and Size is approx 3.1 GB.

I want to transfer this data to some other format to use it more comfortably in sql or csv or other.

Is there any way to do it in simple way.

I know php but 3.1GB is so huge for my system to handle.

suggest any other language(with code to do the same i only understand php) or application that can do the same.

Comment: A normal PHP application should be able to handle this kind of data. It could be that the script will run longer than usual but if you don't load in the whole file all at once, you shouldn't run out of resources.

Comment: how to do that as you have said(if you don't load whole file all at once) . json_decode() need whole file and then decode and stored in ram(i think).  As i know file_get_content();+json_decode(); need 8GB+ of ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used [halaxa/json-machine](https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine).

Usage in case of iteration over JSON is the same as in case of json_decode, but it will not hit memory limit no matter how big your file is. No need to implement anything, just your foreach.

Example:

```
$users = \JsonMachine\JsonMachine::fromFile('500MB-users.json');

foreach ($users as $id => $user) {
    // process $user as usual
}
```

See github readme for more details.

One alternative here is to use the [salsify/jsonstreamingparser](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser)

You need to create your own Listener.

```
$testfile = '/path/to/file.json';
$listener = new MyListener();
$stream = fopen($testfile, 'r');
try {
    $parser = new \JsonStreamingParser\Parser($stream, $listener);
    $parser->parse();
    fclose($stream);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    fclose($stream);
    throw $e;
}
```